# What should we call the area for which the lower border is a Motzkin path?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, terminology

We can draw a Motzkin path from $(0,0)$ to $(n/2,n/2)$ using steps $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$ and $(1/2,1/2)$, such that the path never goes below the line $y=x$. Consider the area bounded by the Motzkin path, the line $x=0$ and the line $y=n/2$. If the Motzkin path is exactly a Dyck path, We know that the area is a Young diagram. What is the area called if the path is a general Motzkin path? I'm looking for a reference about that.

Comment: This question needs to be rewritten more clearly. Also, are you looking for an existing name (e.g. a reference request on what something _is_ called) or a suggestion (e.g. on what something _should be_ called)? The latter is opinion-based, which is one of the flags here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm looking for a reference on what it is called.